# How to extract alpha and other channels from a PNG file with PHP Gmagick?

Tags: php, png, imagick, graphicsmagick, gmagick

I am trying to port 2 graphics magick commands to the [Gmagick php library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmagick.php) (mind: *not* Imagick).
The commands are:

1. `gm convert -matte -flatten image.png output.png`
2. `gm convert -channel Matte -negate image.png output.png`

Basically I am trying to extract the alpha channel from a transparent png into its own file and the image without alpha into another file from a php script.

I have the Imagick equivalents already but I am interested in Gmagick.

Any idea, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Gmagick::separateimagechannel](http://www.php.net/manual/en/gmagick.separateimagechannel.php) to get the channel (get the number of [the matte channel](http://www.php.net/manual/en/gmagick.getimagematte.php)). About removing the matte channel, I have no clue, but it should be possible.

Comment: I think it's possible by separating all channels BUT alpha. But the -negate command is not documented in the php doc...any idea how to negate a image with gmagick ?

Comment: What does the negate command do? Inverting the picture? XOR'ing it?

Comment: From gm man page:
-negate

replace every pixel with its complementary color

The red, green, and blue intensities of an image are negated. White becomes black, yellow becomes blue, etc.